# How to use all currencies in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my google sheets I have a cell(=G13) where I decided what currency should be used.

[Cell G13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6HyJ.png)

If I choose 'Euro' then my currency changes to '€' (Apps script)

It is easy to do with currencies with symbols but special currencies don't work.

For example:
Albanian Lek: Lek1,000
Algerian Dinar: din1,000.12

Also currencies where the symbol is at the end of the amount is a problem in my script.

For example:
Belarusian Ruble: 1,000 p.
Danish Krone: 1,000.12 kr.

This is a part of my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const settings = {
    'us dollar': '$',
     euro: '€'
  };
  let sheet;
  if (!e || !e.value) {
    return;
  }
  const currency = settings[e.value.toLowerCase()];
  if (!currency
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'G13'
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'Start') {
    return;
  }
  const format = ${currency}#,###0.00;
```

Does somebody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about declaring the number format in `settings` object? When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const base = "#,###0.00";
  const settings = { // Please set this for your actual situation.
    'us dollar': `$${base}`,
    'euro': `€${base}`,
    'albanian lek': `"Lek"${base}`,
    'algerian dinar': `"din"${base}`,
    'belarusian ruble': `${base}"p"`,
    'danish krone': `${base}"kr"`,
  };

  let sheet;
  if (!e || !e.value) {
    return;
  }
  const currency = settings[e.value.toLowerCase()];
  if (!currency
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'G13'
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'Start') {
    return;
  }
  const format = currency; // here, "currency" can be directly used as format.


  // do something.


}
```

- This is a sample modification. So, please modify `settings` for your actual situation.

#### Testing:

From your question, please add the values of `Albanian Lek,Algerian Dinar,Belarusian Ruble,Danish Krone` to the dropdown list of the cell "G13". When you use the above-modified script, when you select `Albanian Lek`, `"Lek"${base}` is used as the number format. And, when you select `Belarusian Ruble`, `${base}"p"` as the number format.